# Snowflake - "COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import" error " while loading json data using flatten

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to load below json data from azure stage using flatten

#stage(azure)

```
@json_stage
{
  "location": {
    "city": "Lexington",
    "zip": "40503"
  },
  "price": "75836",
  "sale_date": "4-25-16",
  "sq__ft": "1000"
}
 
-- creating table
create or replace table property_sales(city varchar, zip string, price number, sale_date timestamp_ntz);


 
-- copy into the tabel 
copy into property_sales(city, zip, price, sale_date, sqt_ft) from (select vm.value:city::string, vm.value:zip::number, $1:price::number, to_date($1.sale_date::text,'MM-DD-YY', $1.sq__ft::number) from @json_stage, lateral flatten(input => $1:location) vm);
```

while running above queries, i am getting below error

```
002098 (0A000): SQL compilation error:
COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import
```

i also tried with insert into command instead copy into,

```
insert into property_sales(city, zip, price, sale_date, sqt_ft) select vm.value:city::string, vm.value:zip::number, $1:price::number, to_date($1.sale_date::text,'MM-DD-YY', $1.sq__ft::number) from @json_stage, lateral flatten(input => $1:location) vm;
```

but getting below error

```
ambiguous column name '$1'
```

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the ambiguous column name error:

```
insert into property_sales(city, zip, price, sale_date, sqt_ft) select vm.value:city::string, vm.value:zip::number, j.$1:price::number, to_date(j.$1:sale_date::text,'MM-DD-YY' ), j.$1:sq__ft::number from @json_stage (file_format => jsonformat) j , lateral flatten(input => j.$1:"location" ) VM ;
```

But based on your sample data, I'm not sure if you really need flatten. This should parse (and insert) the sample data:

```
insert into property_sales(city, zip, price, sale_date, sqt_ft) select $1:location.city::string, $1:location.zip::number, $1:price::number, to_date($1:sale_date::text,'MM-DD-YY' ), $1:sq__ft::number from @json_stage (file_format => jsonformat);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message implies not all of the functions normally used in a SELECT are supported in copy transformations. Specifically, from the example above, FLATTEN is not supported https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html.

The solution I would suggest is to create a work table (temporary or transient) with a variant field where you would load the JSON. Then you can execute
INSERT INTO property_sales
SELECT .. FROM work_table
and apply any transformations you need in this SELECT.